# unable make a rest call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, mongodb

hi all i want to make a rest call and redirect the output to a text area in HTML i am attaching the code please correct my mistake if any and please explain how to attach the output of the rest call into the text area in firebug console i get success but i get a reference error data is not defined

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:8300/pink",
    method: "GET",

     contentType: "application/json",
dataType : "json",
success : onSuccess().bind(this), 
 error : function() {
    console.log("Failed node Data");
        }

});
});
onSuccess = function()
{
 console.log("success ");
 document.writeln("pinkar" + data);
 }
 </script>
 <body>
 <input name="results" id="pods"type="radio">pink &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="results"id="testprojects"type="radio">testpink &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="results" id="results" type="radio">results
<div id ="output">
    <div id="podarea"style="display: none;">
             <textarea id="podar" rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="projectarea"style="display: none;">
        <textarea id="proar"rows="4" cols="50"> project area</textarea> 
    </div>
    <div id="resultarea"style="display: none;">
        <textarea id="resar" rows="4" cols="50"> resultarea</textarea> 
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it complicated unnecesarily.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://127.0.0.1:8300/pods",
     method: "GET",
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
       // But you mentioned that returned data type is JSON, make sure to parse it.
            $("#podar").html(data);
     },
     error: function () {
       console.log("Failed node Data");
     }

   });
 });
```

But you mentioned that returned data type is JSON, make sure to parse it or remove `dataType:json`.

Comment: hi i get this in the firebug console
failed node data
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8300/pods. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)
when i enter the URL in the post master plugin  i am getting a json object output as a response

Comment: That is because `CORS` is not enabled on your file. Which language are you using in backend?

Comment: that URL is off MONOGDB  and as off now im using only js and html

Comment: Backend language? Not db? Is it java or python?

Comment: oops i am sorry its python

Comment: Now try to google, how to enable CORS in python mentioning the framework you are using.

Comment: Please dont mind what is this CORS iam new to this can u please tell me what it is all about??

Comment: its not about python or anything else its about web browser we have to disable the web-browser security 
thanks for the help :)

Comment: that is by using "chromium-browser --disable-web-security" in ubuntu im not sure about how to do this in windows platform