# How to get <script src= output to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Javascript how to get the output of a  ?

What i need is

```
var list = <script src="src/users.json"></script>
```

Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: Do you mean you want literally the string above to be stored in `list` or you want the contents of `src/users.json` to be loaded into the variable? If it's the former, just wrap it in quotes `'<script>...</script>'`. Otherwise you'll have to load it with ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable make a rest call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084270/unable-make-a-rest-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make an [ajax call](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and get the response in a variable

```
$.get( "src/users.json", function( data ) {
  var list = JSON.parse( data );
});
```